# firstOrNew where MONTH and YEAR laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$matchThese = array('product_id' => 8789, 'MONTH(date_created)' => '04');
$result = ExpiryPrepayment::firstOrNew($matchThese);
$result->payment_status = 1;
$result->save();

***====>'MONTH(date_created)' => '04'***
```

Help me get condition only month or year in column date_created

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sending an array at a firstornew? This is basically a string that you are building an array with in the eloquent. Inserting an array will not work.  Really the product_id should be a unique so you only need that value in your where.

So it would be something like this...

```
firstOrNew(['product_id' =>  $product_id]);
```

$product_id being the variable of the unique id.
Then if you have tons of products to add just loop over the array of product ids and it will either make a new row at your save or update the product when it finds it first.